# How to open Excel file with 'password to modify', using PowerShell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, passwords, password-protection

I am trying to open an Excel file with 'password to modify' using PowerShell.

I have tried the standard cord to open a password-protected file (see below), but it does not work for 'password to modify'.

```
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $password)
```

I know that I can open such a file using the code below when I use Excel VBA, but is there any equivalent code in PowerShell?

```
Set openExcelFile = Workbooks.Open(filepath, WriteResPassword:=password)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a PowerShell expert, however, the 'password to open' is the 5th param and the 'password to modify' (ie WriteResPassword) is the 6th so I would try with one more `[Type]::Missing` ie

```
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $password)
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already made a module for this:

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Did you give that a try? or if your not allowed to use others modules in your workplace, you could always copy the relevant script from the function here:

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Public/Import-Excel.ps1

Comment: The previous answer solved the issue, but this is also very helpful. Thank you for that.